# Error in connecting to HyperV Server

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, vmware-workstation, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Greetings fellow admins,

*History,*
I recently installed Windows HyperV 2012 on HPZ600 Joined the existing windows Active Directory domain, add the computer on to my Debian DNS Server. No Errors.
I Installed a Windows Server 2012R2 to Manage the HyperV on VMware player.
I have Installed the HyperV Manager in my VM Server

*Problem* 
When I try to connect to the HyperV server from the Server2012, I get the attached error. [image]
Which is "Check that Virtual Machine Management service is running ... etc"

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Hmm, the error I see is "The Computer 'W12HV01' could not be resolved." You sure DNS is working?

Comment: Yes. DNS is working. :)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you dont have the required permissions to connect to Hyper-V. To quickly check it out, you can create 2 identical accounts with admin privileges on both client VM and Hyper-V and try again. Though I think it could also be because of firewall rules. Try to disable firewall on hypervisor node.

Comment: do I have to add the domain admin to local admin of the HyperV?

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be connecting the  hyperv host on hyperv management console.

Check the nic card and network configuration on the virtual host.

Answer (score 1):

If the second server (on which you want to manage the said hyper-v) is not in that domain:

1. You need to edit your hosts file, add the remote server's IP and name
2. Add the remote computer to your 'TrustedHosts':

   `winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="RemoteComputerName"}`
3. If you don't use the 'Administrator' account, lift UAC limitations:

   `reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`
4. Add the remote server in you server manager, Right Click -> Manage As... -> add your domain credentials
5. Right click in Server Manager -> Hyper-V manager

If in Hyper-V manager the target computer is not added automatically, then add it manually (but be careful to start Hyper-V manager from Server Manager, with right click on the target server to get the correct credentials)

If everything works correctly, but you get an 'RPC call failed' or something error instead of VM list, you need a direct connection between the hypervisor and manager machine, and check your firewall for inbound RPC rules. (It is an RPC CALLBACK in real, from the hypervisor to manager)

command soure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759202(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 1):

First check whether vmms service is running by typing command in Windows Command Processor.

Run -  cmd - sc query vmms - enter.  If it is not running type net start vmms.

Second point, check whether the account you are using has admin rights in dsa.msc (Active directory users and computers).  Hyper V has separate group, check there.

Third point, try to add Administrator account on the computer where you are trying to manage Hyper-v by going to Local Users and Groups (lusrmgr.msc).  Go to HyperV group and add Administrator account and make sure you login with Domain Administrator account.